JVM not releasing the memory utilised
I have a java application named seatunnel....
we are currently using it....whenever i run the cluster the jvm takes some space to execute....after execution the jvm does not releases the space...
how can i resolve this issue....
I have used visualvm to see how much space is allocated to the application.
it takes the heap size as
Size: 2,147,483,680 B
Max: 8,589,934,624 B
and the size of jvm as seen in the cmd using bpytop it increases gradually
what to do can anyone suggest??
using bpytop to get the space used by application
using visualvm to get the space used by app
jvm memory keeps on increasing ....how to stop the process to release the memory that has been utilised during the process execution.
The application name that I am using is Apache Seatunnel which is an ingestion tool which ingests data from one source to many different sources...this tool is available in web.....I am using this tool to for ingesting the data.
Apache Seatunnel basically built on java...and so we have created jobs  for eg to ingest data from mysql to mysql and other variety of jobs as well...Now to run these jobs parallelly and anytime we are running a seatunnel cluster on which these jobs gets ran...
so initially the cluster size is 400mb.....after the 1st job run the size taken by the cluster increases to 800mb it may vary depending on the table size or the data size that we are transferring....then cluster does not releases the memory that it has occupied....after 2nd job run the cluster again grows to 1.5gb....the cluster size keep on increasing...and it never releases the memory....we tested out upto 4.5gb the size of the cluster increases and after the job completion it does not release the memory....and subsequently the size of the main memory goes to around 800mb.....after again if we try to run any job the cluster gets crashed....or comes out as it requires more memory and is not able to fulfill it space requirement as the main memory gets to 100mb or 14mb.....
after the cluster crashes....the main memory regains its original space taken by the cluster....so it becomes around 5gb.....we have not tested for more than 5gb of space....
what can we conclude from this.....can we free the space taken by the cluster as shown in the screenshot of cpu utilization....or can we write an external code in java to release the space.....
The Apache seatunnel has provided .sh file to start the cluster and to stop the cluster...but it is not a good practice to start and stop the clusters whenever needed or required....

In the visualvm screenshot heap memory seems to drop at the time of the screenshot. You should take another measure after that. In any case is not even at 2GB. Did you got an out of memory error at some point? Seems normal to me. And we don't know anything about your application, system or usage patterns. We would not have any information to help if there was a real issue.

it is the Garbage Collector (GC) that frees memory; it runs if needed, some threshold is reached - in posted image (visualvm) that seems to be around 1.250MB - we can barely see that the last peak also triggered the GC and it freed up more than the last peak, going down to approx. 125 MB

I have added the detailed description above.

To which cluster are you referring? The problem doesn't seem to be in the JVM, and there is no code related to the issue. Seems offtopic for Stackoverflow, which is a programming Q&A site, not a support site.

Please post your last 10 seconds of your General Log to justpaste.it and share the link for analysis.
